# What is the possible changes in law of gravitation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity

Can someone figure it out for me how this formula arrives

Provide derivation
[courtesy  HC VERMA vol 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baZrj.jpg)

Comment: We actively discourage the use of images of text and equations on Physics SE.  You should edit your question to use a combination of text and [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is the site standard for mathematical expressions.  It is quite common for questions using images of text and equations to be down voted.

Comment: I’m temporarily closing this question because most of the information is hidden in a photograph of text. Your next [edit] will put the question in front of other site users who will consider whether it should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

In short,- it's one of [supergravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity) theories. Gravitational constant is, as it is said by physicists, most poorly *precisely* defined constant from them all. So it's a very active research area trying to beat $G$ new measurement at a greater resolution in some lab. Researchers are at the level for measuring [gravitational acceleration on a cloud of atoms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05171.pdf). The interesting point is that $G$ value produced in different laboratories sometimes don't matches within systematic error bounds. Then there comes a need to explain that difference, which what supergravity theories does. [One of explanation(s)](http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_067_10_1963.pdf) is that gravity on very short distances acts differently than on huge distances. Namely, that gravitational potential takes form :

$$\large V(r) = -\frac {GM}{r}\left(1+ \frac{\alpha}{e^{\,r/r_o}}\right) $$

Where second term is named a *Yukawa potential*. When distances are big, i.e. $r \gg r_o$, then

$$ \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{\alpha}{e^{\,r/r_o}} = 0$$

I.E. Yukawa potential then approcahes zero, and thus at long-scale distances gravitational potential takes usual Newtonian form

$$ V(r) = -\frac {GM}{r} $$

But when distances are very small, i.e. $r \ll r_o$, then

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\alpha}{e^{\,r/r_o}} = \alpha$$

So in tiny distances gravitational potential takes form

$$ V(r) = -\frac {G\,(1+\alpha)M}{r} $$

This expression would explain why gravitation force *may be* lower at short scales, because usually $\alpha$ parameter takes a negative value. It's important to notice, that there is no consensus between scientists about if gravitational constant really gets smaller on short scales. Some experiments say it is, like ["Gravity in mines and boreholes. An investigation of Newton’s law", Steven C. Holding, Frank D. Stacey, and Gary J. Tuck, Phys. Rev. D 33, 3487 – Published 15 June 1986](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.33.3487). They give $\alpha$ estimates in range $[-0.014; -0.0075]$. Also there are attemptions to apply Yukawa potential correction to dwarf and neutron star formation. But also many others don't detect $G(r)$ variations. There is also a broad diversity of explaining theories about such possible $G$ deviation at low scales. Including, but not limited to : interaction of attracting masses in the form of virtual particles exchange; new fifth nature fundamental force; extra dimensions of space, where gravity leaks-to; dependency of gravity force on atomic structure of interacting masses; change of $G$ over time; and etc, etc. **Thus this is a very interesting and active on-going research area, but with no unambiguous conclusions drawn yet**.

Comment: You write that “some experiments say” the gravitational constant “gets smaller on short scales.” Can you link to some such experiments? When I followed this literature all of the experimental results were consistent with Newtonian/Einsteinian gravity, with limits $|\alpha|<10^{-4}$ comparable to the uncertainty in $G$, but I don’t remember any systematic bias in actual $G$ measurements.

Comment: Reference added. There is not much info on positive results, but there are **some**.

Comment: Thanks. I remember that result but I don’t remember its current status. In [this 2008 paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2442), an exclusion plot (Figure 6) shows $|\alpha|<10^{-8}$ for range parameters between $10^2$ and $10^4$ meters, which excludes that result. But the [Eot-Wash group’s home page](https://www.npl.washington.edu/eotwash/results) shows a window including $10^4$ meters where $\alpha\sim10^{-4}$ is still allowed. There’s probably a discussion in [this 2003 review](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.nucl.53.041002.110503), which I can’t access at the moment.